# Installing Rake: invalid gem format

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed Ruby on WinXP. Used rubyinstaller-1.8.6-p383-rc1.exe.

Ran `gem install rake`

Get error:

> Error installing rake: invalid gem format for C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rake-0.8.7.gem

I've tried deleting the cache folder but i keep getting the same error. Tried with Ruby 1.9.1 too. Same error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Manually download the [Rails gem](https://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=307)
2. Unpack it with `gem unpack rails-X.X.X.gem`
3. Search the Rakefile file inside the unpacked dir for lines that start
   with `s.add_dependency`
4. Manually download all the dependencies at rubyforge (each one has its
   own project)
5. Install each one with `gem install xxx.gem`. For Rails 2.0.1 the
   appropriate order is: `activesupport`, `actionpack`, `actionmailer`,
   `activerecord`, `actionresource`, `rake`, `rails`.

And whenever you have an issue with gem, trying updating it first: `gem
update --system`. That usually solves many problems.